# How to remove SharedPreferences after 24 hours in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to remove the SharedPreferences every 24 hours even when the app close.
This is the SharedPreferences:

```
int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounter();
  }

  //Loading counter value on start
  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  //Incrementing counter after click
  _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _counter +=  n;
      prefs.setInt('counter', _counter);
    });
  }
 _remove() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

    prefs.remove('counter');
    });
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Every time you open the app you could call a server to check 24 hours has passed or not and then do the required stuff.

Comment: Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: You mean to ask how to implement an api?

Comment: If you can rely on the client and don't want to make a call to a server, you can store the current date as a string in SharedPreferences. You can parse the string to date and compare with the current date whenever you load your counter.

Comment: yes, how I check from the server that 24 hours passed.

Comment: That would be a long answer. You might want to want to learn how to implment simple api's to communicate with a server. I hope you had a look at @CanTaşpınar's comment above which mentions a simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks, It helps appreciate it.